# Scene Change Error - How do I do it properly?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene, sktransition

I am just wondering why am I getting an error in this code? It says Extra argument 'size' in call.

```
   let transitionToPlayScene = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Down,duration: 1.0)

   let nextScene = Menu4s(size: self.size)
   self.view!.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transitionToPlayScene)
```

Thanks So Much

Comment: I suggest you post the code for `Menu4s`

Answer (score 1):

The class `Menu4s` does not include an initializer with an argument `size`.

```
  1> class Menu4s {}
  2> Menu4s(size: 10)
repl.swift:2:7: error: extra argument 'size' in call
Menu4s(size: 10)
      ^      ~~
```